# Adding point to site VPN to existing VNET and Windows VM

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have set up Windows Machine in Azure in newly created VNET. After that I set up Virtual Network Gateway on this VNET. The gateway is in different subnet as instructed by Microsoft. I am able to connect to to this VPN from my desktop however I am unable to connect to VM.

VM's private IP is 10.0.0.4. It sits on "default" subnet with address range 10.0.0.0/24. VNET address range is defined as 10.0.0.0/24, and default gateway address range is 10.67.0.0/24.

What have I did wrong? Is there any chance to alter the setup or it requires building VNET from scratch and then VMS?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to your Azure VM from the desktop via a VPN connection, you could connect to VM with its private IP. If you have set `GatewaySubnet` address range 10.67.0.0/24, I guess that you should have address space in your VNet like this or you need to expand your address space.

[image]

To configure your VPN, you could refer to [example values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal#example) or [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/step-by-step-creating-an-azure-point-to-site-vpn/ba-p/326264) step-by-step blog. For windows VPN clients, you could select `SSTP(SSL)` or `IKEv2 and SSTP(SSL)` tunnel type.

When you modify your configuration on the Azure portal, you could re-download the VPN client package to re-connect the VPN connection. Let me know if you need further assistance in this case.

Comment: If you follow just the examples everything works fine - we applied the workaround by creating new VNETs and then creating a VM in the VNet. My question remains open: If the error was made and VMs were originally created in VNets without Gateway subnet is it possible to add it later. It seems to me it is not possible.

Comment: When you create a VPN gateway in that VNet, you will create a Gatewaysubnet for creating a VPN gateway or you can reference that existing Gatewaysubnet when you create a VPN gateway but there is only one Gatewaysubnet in one VNet.